# Angular 11 upgrade : aot set to true in angular.json creates issue when opening a component

Tags: angular, angular10, angular11

I have migrated Angular from version 8 through 11 in my application.
There is a strange error where a particular component doesnot load and console throws the following error

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'selectors')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'selectors')
    at core.js:10350:55
    at La (core.js:10172:31)
    at core.js:14786:27
    at Module.Cl (core.js:14823:9)
    at template (my-library.component.html:1:1)
    at Sa (core.js:9614:9)
    at xa (core.js:9418:13)
    at Za (core.js:10698:5)
    at core.js:9283:9
    at xa (core.js:9443:13)
    at Gg.create (core.js:25141:13)
    at $h.createComponent (core.js:23180:47)
    at e.activateWith (router.js:5324:40)
    at it.activateRoutes (router.js:2134:40)
    at router.js:2085:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at x (zone-evergreen.js:798:39)
    at x (zone-evergreen.js:750:21)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860:21
    at l.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28578:33)
    at l.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:40)
    at s.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:51)
    at v (zone-evergreen.js:569:39)
    at u.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484:25)
    at m (zone-evergreen.js:1621:18)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.y (zone-evergreen.js:1658:25)
```

I tried disabling aot and optimization flag in build section of angular.json and the error seems to go away and component loads fine too. I'm clueless as how aot might cause this kind of issue.

my-library.component.html -> line 1

```
<div>
  <div class="Tabs-header">
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: I took a big effort to look through 500 lines of code and found out that the error was infact right . Some redundant old code in HTML was causing this error to poup . Not deleting this post , so that it helps someone falling into similar issue